# Opencv stopped working on Android 6.0

Tags: android, opencv, android-context

I am using Opencv on my application and it works fine with Android 4.3 but it doesn't even open with Android 6.0.

I looked up for a solution on SO, and found one that says to set the package name. So I did it.

Follow code:

```
public static boolean initOpenCV(String Version, final Context AppContext,
        final LoaderCallbackInterface Callback)
{
    AsyncServiceHelper helper = new AsyncServiceHelper(Version, AppContext, Callback);
    Intent intent = new Intent("org.opencv.engine.BIND");
    intent.setPackage("org.opencv.engine");
    if (AppContext.bindService(intent,
            helper.mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        AppContext.unbindService(helper.mServiceConnection);
        InstallService(AppContext, Callback);
        return false;
    }
}
```

But now I am getting the following error:

```
11-18 10:14:43.447 24901-24930/br.com.ibramed.dermos E/AndroidRuntime:      android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
11-18 10:14:43.447 24901-24930/br.com.ibramed.dermos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:571)
11-18 10:14:43.447 24901-24930/br.com.ibramed.dermos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:310)
11-18 10:14:43.447 24901-24930/br.com.ibramed.dermos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
11-18 10:14:43.447 24901-24930/br.com.ibramed.dermos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:319)
```

in the following code:

```
case InstallCallbackInterface.NEW_INSTALLATION:
        {
            Looper.prepare();
            Log.d("Debug", ""+mAppContext);
            AlertDialog InstallMessage = new AlertDialog.Builder(mAppContext).create();
            InstallMessage.setTitle("Package not found");
            InstallMessage.setMessage(callback.getPackageName() + " package was not found! Try to install it?");
            InstallMessage.setCancelable(false); // This blocks the 'BACK' button
            InstallMessage.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes", new OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    callback.install();
                }
            });

            InstallMessage.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "No", new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    callback.cancel();
                }
            });

            InstallMessage.show();
        } break;
```

I have searched and found some people saying to keep track of the main Context, because Threads doesn't have context. But my app already does this and use the main context to create the AlertDialogs and it still doesn't work.

The error is when the app show the AlertDialog.

I really don't know what else to do. Can someone help?

Comment: Does anything you're doing in that section of code require a permission?  The only problem I had getting stuff running on Marshmallow is the new way permissions are handled in code in Marshmallow.

Comment: Maybe Internet in order to download the opencv package. But I read that Internet is a normal request and only including in manifest is enough. I also tried to run on Android 5.3 and it run normally.

Comment: Ok, so What I did was a temporary solution. I installed the OpenCV Manager from Google Play manually and the app started working.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know in service or Aplication class you cant get context with View for android 6.0, so when OpenCv tries to show AlertDialog it does not know to what activity bind dialog and crashes. 
Try to init OpenCv in Activity onCreate method before usage.

My working init method in MainActivity (code on kotlin):

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_9, this, object : BaseLoaderCallback(this@HistoryActivity) {
                override fun onManagerConnected(status: Int) {
                    if (LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS == status)
                        Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV was loaded")
                    else
                        super.onManagerConnected(status)
                }
            })
    }
```